# How to redirect from json response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an ajax call(from jquery) to login.php and receive a json response like-{"response":{"error": "false", "user_id" :"141","name": "as"}}.
now i want to redirect user to home.php, but dont know how.
any suggestion or sample code will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: here is my ajax call-  $.post("action.php",{email:email, password:pass, action:action}, function(response){
    //code here    
     },"json");  response has user id(who logged in) now i want to redirect user to home.php along with his id.how?

Answer (score 1):

In the function which consumes the JSON input, simpy check for response value (or any other condition you want), and if match, do the redirect:

```
$.post("action.php", { email: email, password:pass, action:action }, function(json)
{
    if (json.response.error)
        $(window.location).attr('href', 'home.php?id=' + json.response.user_id);
}, 'json');
```

In the more general scenario you would also need to check that login.php actually DOES return, i.e., you supply a success and failure handler; the success handler, if the JSON exists, if the response is properly formatted, does its thing; all other cases would redirect to home.php.

Consider adding a dialog to explain to the user what exactly happened, and placing the location redirect in the dialog dismiss handler.

**Consider**: that your whole response appears to be inside a dictionary called "response". This is not necessary, and forces to write things like `json.response.error` and `json.response.user_id` instead of `json.user_id`.

Also, I assume that the login is also saving login information in a session; I wouldn't trust the redirected id. If you did, any user with FireBug could log in as any other user with the same password.

```
// action.php
// receive parameters
if ($login_ok)
{
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    Header('Content-Type: application/json');
    die(json_encode(array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        ...
    )));
}
// Send along the error
```

Then you redirect to home.php WITHOUT the user_id, and home.php recovers the user_id from the session.

Comment: here is my ajax call- $.post("action.php",{email:email, password:pass, action:action}, function(response){ //code here  },"json"); response has user id(who logged in) now i want to redirect user to home.php along with his id.how?

Comment: Edited my answer, but your architecture appears to have a security vulnerability. So I provided also an alternative. Hope this is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working fine and all you need is to redirect the user to a new URL. Use this JavaScript code:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com.pk"; //whichever URL you want
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the response, and see if there is an error?? try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  dataType: json,
  success: function(data) {
      //login success
      if(!data.response.error){
         windown.location='/home.php';
      }else{
         ...
      }
   }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect using Javascript you can use the following code

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
```

If you want to redirect using php you can use the following code

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: if i am writting $result = json_decode($response); header('Location:welcome.php'); so it is not redirecting to welcome.php, its taking too much time to redirect how can i solve this